# How to connect Visual Studio 2015 with windows phone device?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-mobile, windows-10-universal

Seems like easy thing, but I'm trying for over half an hour and it doesn't want to work. I want to connect my windows phone to visual studio to debug windows 10 universal app.

What I've already tried:

I've set "Developer mode" and "Device discovery" as [described here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/09/just-released-windows-10-application-deployment-tool/). It lead me to [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#set-group-policies-or-registry-keys) where I've read about [WinAppDeployCmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt203806.aspx). I tried to use this app this way in CMD:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86"
WinAppDeployCmd devices
```

It doesn't see any devices connected.

Then I learned about something like [Device Portal for Mobile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile#setup). They told me to type in my browser:

> http://127.0.0.1:10080

Doesn't work. If it worked, I would (according to this tutorial) type some code that will pair my PC with phone, but, as it doesn't work, I can't.

Can you please, help me with this? Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you have the code for the application that you want to debug?

Comment: On the Visual Studio 2015 toolbar, select Debug, ARM, make sure debug button has Device selected and click it. How did you get the app onto the phone in the first place?

Comment: @GlenThomas App is not on my phone yet. This is what Visual Studio shows me, when I did what you told me to do: "DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945906"

Comment: Have you tried deploying to an emulator?

Comment: Try to reset the phone (Setting -> System -> About -> Reset button. I got kind of the same problem (not exactly error code, but weird one as well), and it helps.